# Better way to write Case When Multiple conditions

Tags: sql, excel, openedge, case-when, progress-db

I have have written the below query to help me segment my data into different cells. This has over 200 conditions so i have only provided a small sample. Is there a better way for me to write this statement because from research Progress will not let me do more than 50 `CASE WHEN....THEN` statements.

```
SELECT    

Company_0.CompanyID 
    ,Company_0.CoaCompanyName
    ,(CASE 
    WHEN Company_0.CompanyID = 7942127 THEN 'BLUE'
    WHEN Company_0.CompanyID = 7950986 THEN 'BLUE'
    WHEN Company_0.CompanyID = 7955733 THEN 'BLUE'
    WHEN Company_0.CompanyID = 7955922 THEN 'BLUE'
    WHEN Company_0.CompanyID = 7956194 THEN 'RED'
    WHEN Company_0.CompanyID = 9166261 THEN 'RED'
    WHEN Company_0.CompanyID = 9167003 THEN 'YELLOW'
    WHEN Company_0.CompanyID = 9167015 THEN 'YELLOW
ELSE NULL
END' AS 'CELL'
```

When the results are returned it should look something like this:

```
ID              COMPANY NAME          CELL
-------------------------------------------------------
7942127             A                 BLUE
7950986             B                 BLUE
7955733             C                 BLUE
7955922             D                 BLUE
7956194             E                 RED
9166261             F                 RED
9167003             G                 YELLOW
9167015             H                 YELLOW
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `in`

```
SELECT    
Company_0.CompanyID 
    ,Company_0.CoaCompanyName
    ,(CASE 
    WHEN Company_0.CompanyID in( 7942127,7950986,7955733,7955922 ) THEN 'BLUE'
    WHEN Company_0.CompanyID in( 7956194,9166261 ) THEN 'RED'
    WHEN Company_0.CompanyID in( 9167003,9167015 ) THEN 'YELLOW'

ELSE NULL
END' AS 'CELL'
```

Comment: Fantastic Thank you i will see it it lets me do it for the full field